# Trying to write filename to csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

My code determines if the contents of the file returns `True` or `False` and output the results to a .csv.

I would like to write the filename also to the csv in the same row.

**Error message**

```
for i in range(vt_result_file):
NameError: name 'vt_result_file' is not defined
```

**Code**

```
import os
import json
import csv

path=r'./output/'
csvpath='C:/Users/xxx/Documents/csvtest'
file_n = 'file.csv'

def vt_result_check(path):
    vt_result = False
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

        # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
        # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
        # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
        # Look for any positive detected URLs
        sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                        'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
        vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
                                                 for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))

        # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Dr.Web category') == "known infection source"

        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
        threats = ("elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content")
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats

    return str(vt_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(file_n, 'w') as output:
        for i in range(vt_result_file):
            output.write(vt_result_file, vt_result_check(path))
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: for i in range(vt_result_file):
NameError: name 'vt_result_file' is not defined

Comment: Do you want a true/false for each file that you examine? I think your `for` loop nesting might be adrift.

Comment: What are you trying to loop over? That variable doesn't exist...

Comment: That variable doesn't exist in the scope you're trying to use it. It only exists within the `with` block in the `vt_result_check` function

Comment: @sundance Thanks you for your reply! Can I just move the writeout code to the vt_result_check function block then since I want to be able to write the filename in the csv?

Comment: Since ```sample_types``` and ```threats``` have constant values, you don't need to redefine them over and over inside those loops. Move them to the top of the function or, even better, outside of the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

`vt_result_file` only exists as a **local** variable to `vt_result_check`, your error is saying this variable does not exist at the bottom of the file.

Plus, (even though it doesn't matter) you are referring to that variable before you called the function that creates that variable.

---

There is nothing you are looping over in the main function area. And your `check` function only returns a single value.

Therefore, you can only write out one CSV row

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(file_n, 'w') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow([file_n, vt_result_check(path)])
```

---

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, you want something like this

```
with open(file_n, 'w') as output:  # Open the CSV file
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for filename in os.listdir(path):  # Loop over all files to check
        full_filename = path + filename
        with open(full_filename, 'r') as vt_result_file: 
            # Load the file and check it 
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)
            writer.writerow([full_filename, check_file(full_filename)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually want the vt_result_file listed in the csv since I would like to display the name of the file that I'm checking to be true or false.

Comment: Then you need to completely rewrite your code so that `vt_result_check` takes **one file**, instead of looping over a path. In other words, you need to move `for filename in os.listdir(path)` **outside** of that function. -- See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you're trying to use a variable, `vt_result_file`, that is not in scope--it doesn't exist in the part of the script that you're trying to access it in. You are trying to use it here, presumably to loop over a set of files:

```
    for i in range(vt_result_file):
        output.write(vt_result_file, vt_result_check(path))
```

but `vt_result_file` only exists in the `vt_result_check` function, which hasn't even been called when you try to use the variable in `for i in range(vt_result_file)`.

You're also duplicating work, as your `vt_result_check` function iterates through all the files in a directory, so you don't need to do the same thing to get the results.

It looks as though your main function is also not working correctly, as you're iterating through the files, setting the contents to `vt_data`, but you only do further analysis on the last set of data:

```
    with open(path + filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
        # this is done for every file
        vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

    # check the indentation level of the code
    # it'll only run on the last value of vt_data
    sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                    'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
    vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
                                             for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))
```

I think you probably want to run the analysis code on every file, and then save the result for each file. An easy way to do this is using a dictionary -- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict  Here's a suggestion for how to restructure your code:

```
def vt_result_check(path):

    # initialise an empty dictionary for your results
    results = {}

    sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                            'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
    threats = ("elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content")

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
            # set this to false for each file
            vt_result = False
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

            # do all your analysis here
            vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
                                                     for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))

            # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
            vt_result |= vt_data.get('Dr.Web category') == "known infection source"

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
            vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats

            # save the file name and the result in your dict
            results[vt_result_file] = str(vt_result)

    # return the dictionary
    return results
```

You can then print out your results as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result_dict = vt_result_check(path)
    with open(file_n, 'w') as output:
        for i in result_dict:
            output.write(i + ": " + result_dict[i])
```

Comment: @i_alarmed_alien Thanks for your help! After implementing your suggestions I'm now getting these two error messages:

File "/7_27_python_script.py", line 35, in <module>
    result_dict = vt_result_check(path)
  File "7_27_python_script.py", line 26, in vt_result_check
    vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats
NameError: name 'threats' is not defined

Comment: I cut out a load of your code -- you will need to reinstate the lines that I removed. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @bedford please accept the answer and/or vote it up if it was helpful.